# GoJS dragging nodes from a group to the diagram

Tags: javascript, gojs

I am fairly new to the goJS library and currently developing a graph GUI editor. 
I simply want to know if a node I dragged out from a group node has been dropped to the main diagram. I am aware about the memberRemoved property in the group class, but I could only obtain the data of the selected node and the data of it's former parent node. The memberAdded property also doesn't seem apply to items added to the diagram. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of finding out when a node has been moved out from a group and onto the diagram's background.

The easiest would be to add some code just after the node has been removed from the group and added as a top-level Part in the background. In the case of the Regrouping sample, https://gojs.net/latest/samples/regrouping.html, that would mean adding some code just after the super call to **CommandHandler.addTopLevel Parts**.